# How to Find (a^b^c)%MOD

Tags: algorithm, modulo

How to find (a^b^c)%MOD where Mod =10^9+7 and a,b and c are very large numbers .
Please help to solve this problem

Comment: Is there a certain programming language you have in mind? or just looking for a psuedocode solution?  Are a,b,c integer? BigNums?

Comment: @BrandonYates I code in C++.All are BigNums especially b is very big,a and c are in integer range though

Comment: `(a^b)^c` or `a^(b^c)`?

Comment: It might help to note that 10^9+7 is prime.

Comment: Can you use the c math library? The solution is nearly trivial. pow(a,pow(b,c)) % modulus.  Or do you mean to say a,b,c are integers in the group Z(10^9+7)

Comment: @barakmanos a^(b^(c))

Comment: @Brandon Yates `pow(b,c)` may overflow (and even if not, `pow(a,pow(b,c))` will almost certainly overflow).

Comment: @barakmanos absolutly agreed.It will always overflow

Comment: @Brandon Yates: Quoting from the question: "a,b and c are very large numbers".

Comment: This is done efficiently with exponentiation by squaring. You can find pseudo-code [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method)

Comment: I think he edited that in, or i just misread.  Anyway you should use an arbitrary precision library like GMP. It's basically a one line solution with GMP.  The library is open source so check the source if you want to know how it works at low level

Comment: @BrandonYates Is their no better way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @erickson Please explain a bit

Comment: I would definitely use a library instead of reinventing the wheel. Maybe boost has something I'm not sure.  I'd use GMP though.

Comment: @user3306991 No, you go read the article.

Comment: @erickson Oh please this question is related to algorithms part also

Comment: I've already put way more into my comments than you have in your question. Show us what you've tried, and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has modular exponentiation built in so you can do:

```
pow(a,pow(b,c,M-1),M)
```

The M-1 is due to [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem):

```
a**(p-1) = 1  mod p
```

This tells us that pow(a,x,M) is the same as pow(a,x%(M-1),M), so we only need to work out b**c modulo M-1.

Note that in Python pow(a,b,M) computes a**b%M ([documentation for pow](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow)).

Comment: yeah you are right.How to find b**c modulo M-1 if b is very large digit say of form C(2n,n) where n can be as large as 10^5.

Comment: You only need b modulo M-1, so just compute the factorials modulo M-1.  C(2n,n) is (2n!)/n!/n!

Comment: But how?As now Mod is no longer prime number so i cant apply invers modulo .

Comment: You can do it for each prime factor of M-1 and then combine the results using the Chinese remainder theorem.  There is a good explanation [here](http://www.quora.com/Algorithms/What-are-some-efficient-algorithms-to-compute-nCr-mod-m)